# Откуда в русском языке берутся буквенные орфограммы?

Tags: орфография, общие-вопросы

**В идеальном языке** не должно быть орфограмм, но идеальных языков не существует. Поэтому в русском языке орфограммы имеются, недотягивает он до идеального.

А теперь **пофантазируем**. Что нужно изменить в русском языке, чтобы он стал идеальным языком?

**Общая причина всех орфограмм** ― это необходимость **выбора** (А или О, Д или Т, Ь или Ъ). Но ведь есть слова, где нет орфограмм, например: ***пол, соль, тень.***

Однако в большинстве слов они есть, так откуда же они берутся? **Я могу назвать 4 изменения** (теоретически возможных, но практически неприемлемых). А вы?

Может показаться, что это **праздный вопрос**, но в действительности он раскрывает **причины существования орфограмм (а это практически важно).**

И кроме того, **раскрепощает наше мышление**, считающее орфограммы  неотъемлемой частью письма.

Comment: Поставил плюс, но так и не понял, что такое орфограмма. :)

Comment: Артем,  орфограмма (= пиши правильно) – это когда вы не знаете, какую буковку писать. К примеру, слышите звук И и думаете: что же мне написать, Е или И?  А может быть, Я? Если вы так думаете, то это орфограмма. Итак, орфограмма – это буква, которую приходится выбирать из двух или даже трех вариантов.  Получается, что это не идеальный язык с однозначным соответствием звук – буква. Вот если бы роботы захотели придумать себе собственный  язык, он уж точно был  бы без орфограмм.

Comment: Ясно теперь, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

ОТВЕТ ИСПРАВЛЕН 30.11.2020 (подпись: Sharon) Неплохая тема, но она была изложена не лучшим образом.

Что нужно **изменить** в русском языке, чтобы в нем не было буквенных орфограмм?

**А. Надо избавиться от фонетических орфограмм**

Фонетические орфограммы составляют основную часть буквенных орфограмм. Их причина ― **фонетическое чередование звуков**, например: вода ― воды (О/А), снег ― снега (Г/К). Если в устной речи следовать **орфографическому чтению**, то есть произносить смысловые звуки (фонемы), то фонетических орфограмм не будет.

**Однако это НЕВОЗМОЖНО сделать, так как устная речь строится по собственным правилам орфоэпии.** Изменяя смысловой звук, мы жертвуем частью смысла, но при этом обеспечиваем **удобство произношения** (плавность сочетания согласных, экономичную энергоемкость гласных).

**Б. Надо навести идеальный порядок в графике (однозначность соответствия звук-буква).**

**1) Система гласных звуков и букв**

У нас 5 гласных звуков (фактически 10 единиц с учетом их мягких и твердых вариантов) и 10 гласных букв, то есть **система вроде бы симметричная.**

Но работает эта система неидеально, так как буквы **Ё и Э не являются полноценными по своим функциям:** Ё не пишется в безударных слогах, а Е часто заменяет Э после твердого согласного.

**Можно ли сделать букву Ё полноценной,** то есть **писать без ударения.**
Фантастика?

Но что здесь особенного, дело только **в привычке,** например: мёд - мёдовый. Все равно в безударной позиции **Ё редуцируется** и произносится как И. В конце концов, **это просто буквенный знак**, только с особой историей.

Многие борются за букву Ё, предлагают уравнять ее в правах с обычными парными гласными, да только не знают, как это сделать. Вот, есть вариант, но **вы ведь против, не правда ли?** Это даже в сознании не укладывается, так велика роль традиции.

**Сделать букву Э полноценной,** то есть писать: тэннис. Теоретически можно, но практически абсолютное нереально, так как произношение заимствованных слов часто **меняется** от твердого к мягкому по мере того, как слово осваивается в русском языке.

**2) Надо навести порядок в группе шипящих и Ц (непарных по твердости-мягкости)**

Изменяем правило употребления  гласных после шипящих и Ц и мягкого знака после шипящих, всё приводим к единообразию. Думаете, получится? Увы, нет.

В действительности при выборе написаний **в этой группе** учитываются **традиции письма и произношения**, а также используется **важный признак подобия для сходных слов**: несёт/течёт, унесённый/увлечённый, лить/жечь.

**3) Надо навести порядок при обозначении звука Й по единым правилам**

**Используем только мягкий разделительный знак.** Запретить написания вида **йогурт.** Можно, конечно, это сделать, но **польза от этого для всеобщей грамотности будет мизерная.**

Тут интересно вспомнить, что все наши орфографические реформы занимались преимущественно **небольшим классом графических орфограмм.**

**ВЫВОД**

Ничего не получается, что же делать? Да ничего не надо делать, но кое-что надо четко понять. Нельзя смешивать графические и фонетические орфограммы, результат от этого получается крайне негативный.

**Графические орфограммы** дополняют правила письма в части обеспечения однозначного обозначения звук-буква, а **фонетические орфограммы** связаны с изменением звуков в слабых позициях. Орфографические принципы в основе их решений также **совершенно разные.**

А у нас их различают? Что-то я сомневаюсь в этом, **об этом и весь мой "фантастический" рассказ.**

Comment: Что делать? Чтоб детишки меньше пялились в телефоны и больше читали нормальной литературы. Как? это уже следующий вопрос...

Comment: А где найти нормальную литературу?  Правила обычно не объясняют, их нужно просто заучивать. Между тем практически все они имеют объяснение. Где детишкам прочитать об этом? Может быть, если бы они понимали суть правил, то осваивали бы грамотное письмо успешнее и быстрее . А пока они изучают в школе никому не понятные орфографические принципы (вернее, фантазии на их тему), но не знают, что с этими принципами делать. Только время зря тратят.

Comment: Жасмин, Вы в комментарии поднимаете слишком масштабную проблему. Почему детям в школе не объясняют правила? Потому что не могут и не хотят. Не могут, так как есть программа и на "лишние" объяснения надо найти время. И в основном не хотят, разве что учитель - энтузиаст и очень любит свою работу. А почему программа такая, какая есть? И почему в школах мало энтузиастов? Такое общество. То есть это системная проблема.

Comment: @Jasmin,  странно, что это вы пишете.